# Minimal value of an indexed 2d list in Python

Tags: python, list

In Python, given a 2d list of the form:

```
L = [[0, 4],[10, 2],[20, 1],[30, 2]]
```

How can I obtain the pair that contains the minimum value in the second place? In other words, how to obtain the pair x,y such that y is the smallest among all ys?

That is, in the list above that would be `L[2]=[20,1]`. I could not find how the `min` function can be used here.

---

Edit: I was not able to do a proper search in SO for possible repeated questions. OP agrees to close if needed.

Comment: Better dupe target: [Tuple pairs, finding minimum using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802128/tuple-pairs-finding-minimum-using-python)

Comment: The first comment totally answer my question. I was looking in SO for a while to find this, how did you find it so fast?

Comment: Searched for "[python] min tuples" on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
second_vals = [tup[1] for tup in L]
min_i = second_vals.index(min(second_vals))
print(L[min_i])
```

Output:

```
[20,1]
```

the better way to solve this problem (cleaner and taking O(1) space instead of O(n))
would be to use min with a key function

```
print(min(L, key=lambda pair: pair[1]))
```

output:

```
[20,1]
```

Hope I could help :)

Comment: Well, that's _one_ way, but it would be much cleaner to use `min` with a `key` function instead.

Comment: you are right thank you, I just added it to my answer :)